# Importxml Could not fetch url

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

This is the website: `https://www.thefork.com/search/?cityId=326512&promotionOnly=true`

I want a list of all the restaurants names, including the % off, website and address.
I tried all sorts of things, nothing worked. So I thought to make it even broader like so:
`=importxml("https://www.thefork.com/search/?cityId=326512&promotionOnly=true","//h2/*")` but nothing (If I'm correct, this says to take everything between`<h 2>< /h2>` right?

Then I tried to only take the websites with:
`=importxml("https://www.thefork.com/search/?cityId=326512&promotionOnly=true","//a@href/*")` if I'm correct? nothing.....

So now I'm reading up on this formula, but I haven't been able to narrow down my search to what I want to achieve. I first thought that maybe it's not possible because there is an option to login to the website, but then... this page is public and no need to logon.

Comment: The right xpath could be "//a/@href" for instance ... nevertheless I am afraid it will noy be possible because the server of the site probably rejects google request to prevent web scrapping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to google sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)